# remote true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting **template missing error**, don't know why. I tried sevral things but could not find why. Initially I was directly sending params through ajax method and there was no error. I changed it to form_for. Now I am getting this error. Can anyone spot what is the error here??

My code goes like this.

```
<%= form_for(car,:format => :js,:method => :get, :remote => true, :class => "carformtag",:id=>"carformtag",:url => (conversion.comment_flag.present? ? converted_path : edit_converted_path), :validate => true) do |p|%>
      <span class="ckbox ckbox-primary col-md-12" style="padding: 0px">
            <%= p.check_box :reason_one, {:class => "reason_one history_checked_unchecked", :id => "reason_one"}, "true", "false" %>
            <label for="reason_one">Collection not good</label>
          </span>
      <span class="col-md-12">
        <%= p.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success", remote: true, 'data-disable-with' => "Please wait.."%>
      </span>
<% end %>

Controller Code:    

     def converted            
        @recommend = Car.find(params[:id])            
        @prescription.update(update_params)
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `render json: {data: "success"}` or whatever you want to respond with in your controller action. You also shouldn't need remote: true twice. Just putting it on the form_for should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller give the format of template you want to render ,which in your case I think is js. 
In controller give it as :-

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
```